# Payment Method: Checkout convert price to cryptocurrency via API

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, payment-methods

I am trying to make a `payment module` via **cryptocurrency**.

I want to show in the success (final) page ( checkout ) the amount of crypto that clients needs to pay.

I have embedded the api and I call it with curl.

What directories should I add ? How the conversion is made?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to clear the payments via 3d party provider (e.g. coinpaiments or bipay) it's better to use their API to retrieve the rates.

If you use your own methods you can use any API, for example coinapi

Also consider to use this [extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/kozeta-currency.html) to automatically retrieve the rates and display product prices in selected currencies and required precision